# how to implement scheduler for playing videofiles in android

Tags: android

I have a list of time stream and video files too. and I just want to schedule that file based on time which I have already. It's just like a normal advertisement portal where each Ad or video plays in certain time intervals
For Example I have three video file which is play/run at 9:00-9:02 , 9:02-9:04,and 9:04-9:06 respectively and after that many others video file which is running whole day as per time mentioned in the scheduler.
Anybody response is really appraciable

Comment: take a look at AlarmManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Can you Please attach snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code how you can use AlarmManager to your project

Configure and start your AlarmManager

```
private void setAlarmManager() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, YourAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the time you want
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 34);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 6);
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    //we must check the version code, because start from kitkat AlarmManager.set isn't set the
    //AlarmManager to the exact time
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    else
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Make your receiver class

```
public class YourAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do what you want here
    }
}
```

Register your receiver to manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".YourAlarmReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Thanks # Hendra Wijaya Djiono

Comment: I have a date format also that need to be validate as well..How can I validate time, date and associated video with in scheduler, and run a video files only in the given time and date slot..